Does polars not distinguish between tuple and list?
For Pandas I sometimes cast nested lists to tuples e.g. to be able to drop duplicates (being aware that order of the elements would matter). For Polars there does not seem to be a difference between lists and tuples. I can't find anymore info on this. Could someone elaborate this a little?
import polars as pl

dftuple_pl = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [("a", "a"), ("a", "a")],
                           "col2": [("b", "b"), ("b", "b")]})

dflist_pl = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"]],
                          "col2": [["b", "b"], ["b", "b"]]})

print(dftuple_pl.equals(dflist_pl))
# True

print(dftuple_pl.unique())
# shape: (1, 2)
# ┌────────────┬────────────┐
# │ col1       ┆ col2       │
# │ ---        ┆ ---        │
# │ list[str]  ┆ list[str]  │
# ╞════════════╪════════════╡
# │ ["a", "a"] ┆ ["b", "b"] │
# └────────────┴────────────┘

print(dflist_pl.unique())
# shape: (1, 2)
# ┌────────────┬────────────┐
# │ col1       ┆ col2       │
# │ ---        ┆ ---        │
# │ list[str]  ┆ list[str]  │
# ╞════════════╪════════════╡
# │ ["a", "a"] ┆ ["b", "b"] │
# └────────────┴────────────┘

import pandas as pd

dftuple_pd = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [("a", "a"), ("a", "a")],
                           "col2": [("b", "b"), ("b", "b")]})

dflist_pd = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"]],
                          "col2": [["b", "b"], ["b", "b"]]})

print(dftuple_pd.equals(dflist_pd))
# False

print(dftuple_pd.drop_duplicates())
#      col1    col2
# 0  (a, a)  (b, b)

print(dflist_pd.drop_duplicates())
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

So, is it useless (or maybe even impossible) to cast columns to tuples in Polars (e.g. using .map_elements(tuple)?

What goal are you trying to achieve? As you could see, polars had no trouble dropping duplicates with lists.

Your test cases are not complete.  You do not print the objects without running the unique() or drop_duplicates() functions.  You also did not cast your list to tuple, you defined another object with the same members.  Did pandas 'drop' the duplicate members because tuple doesn't allow them?  or were they only filtered on the print()?

As a more direct answer to your question, it is not necessary to casts lists to tuple in polars, because polars has a built-in unique() function that works on lists the same way  drop_duplicates() works on tuple in pandas.  It may be useful for other reasons, but not the case you've put forth.

Polars does not have a tuple type. In Rust: A tuple is a collection of values of different types - which may have something to do with it. Earlier versions of Polars would read tuples as an object type column, rendering them unusable. It was later changed to read them as if they were lists instead.

@BallpointBen: I just want to understand polars. Just transferred a big project from pandas to polars and recognized some differences. Also I did not gain any performance boots from switching. But my project is I'd say 90% filling lists and 10% data wrangling with pandas/polars. Now I am trying to improve performance e.g. by removing unnecessary dtype casts and stuff.

@Kevin: I did all these tests. Just didn't post them here to not bore you :).

But a tuple is also hashable and to my understanding that is a requirement to compare it. I've also figured that polars can check dflist_pl.with_columns(...(pl.col('a') == ["a", "a"]..., whereas pandas cannot check ...(dflist_pd.a == ["a", "a"]).

Polars does not uses Python types, but rather has its own data types (See the User Guide and Reference).
This also applies to Pandas, and both Polars and Pandas have an Object data type they use for generic data types they do not have explicit support for. In the case of pandas, this includes strings, tuples, and lists.
You could explicitly tell it to use the pl.Object data type when creating the DataFrame, but using the Polars datatypes is more efficient than using generic python Objects overall. Just like you would use pl.String for strings, you should use pl.List for lists and tuples.
(Alternatively, you can use pl.Array if your nested data has a fixed length, or pl.Struct if you want nested columns)
import polars as pl
# Seriously, don't do this. Avoid pl.Object() as much as possible.
df = pl.DataFrame([
    pl.Series("tuples", [("a", "a"), ("a", "a")], dtype=pl.Object()),
    pl.Series("lists", [["b", "b"], ["b", "b"]], dtype=pl.Object()),
])

